# How to eager load child model's sum value for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I have an `Order` model, it has many `items`, it looks like this

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  def total
    items.sum('price * quantity')
  end
end
```

And I have an order index view, querying order table like this

```
  def index
    @orders = Order.includes(:items)
  end
```

Then, in the view, I access total of order, as a result, you will see tons of `SUM` query like this

```
SELECT SUM(price * quantity) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 1]]
SELECT SUM(price * quantity) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 2]]
SELECT SUM(price * quantity) FROM "items" WHERE "items"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 3]]
...
```

It's pretty slow to load `order.total` one by one, I wonder how can I load the sum in a eager manner via single query, but still I can access `order.total` just like before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
subquery = Order.joins(:items).select('orders.id, sum(items.price * items.quantity) AS total').group('orders.id')

@orders = Order.includes(:items).joins("INNER JOIN (#{subquery.to_sql}) totals ON totals.id = orders.id")
```

This will create a subquery that sums the total of the orders, and then you join that subquery to your other query.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up two options for this in this blog post on using [find_by_sql](https://www.sqlbot.co/blog/rails-find_by_sql-make-your-page-load-35-times-faster) or joins to solve this.

For your example above, using find_by_sql you could write something like this:

```
Order.find_by_sql("select
  orders.id,
  SUM(items.price * items.quantity) as total
from orders 
join items
   on orders.id = items.order_id
group by 
  order.id")
```

Using joins, you could rewrite as:

```
Order.all.select("order.id, SUM(items.price * items.quantity) as total").joins(:items).group("order.id")
```

Include all the fields you want in your select list in both the select clause and the group by clause.  Hope that helps!